# Java class not recognizing external method

Tags: java, class

I'm having trouble getting a class to call a method from another class within the same package. The ultimate use of the calling class will be to handle changes to an ArrayList, but right now, I can't even manage to get the calling class to find the class it's supposed to be calling.

Class with method:

```
public class Animal {
    String species;
    public void setInfo(String spec){
    this.species = spec;
    }

}
```

Caller class:

```
public class AnimalListHandler {
   Animal animal = new Animal();
   String species = "cow";
   animal.setInfo(species); // identifier expected, can't find symbol species

}
```

As far as I can tell, I've done everything recommended in the documentation and in other threads, and it's still not working. I even tried import AnimalList.Animal and that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the given link solves your problem?

Comment: Sotirios and user 3437460, My issue is different from the one in the link provided. The link provided deals with statements outside method calls and method calls inside the same class, not two separate classes interacting with each other. I was able to fix it though. For some reason closing the package and opening it again fixed the problem. Thanks NetBeans...

Comment: Uh no. Your `AnimalListHandler`, as it is, will not compile. You're trying to invoke a method directly in the body of a class. That's never going to work and that's what the compiler error is telling you.

Comment: @BethM Try executing all your codes from `AnimalListHandler` within a method such as a `public static void main(String[] args)`. Reopening NetBeans will not solve your error. Your code needs to be contained within a method.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the code before submitting. The Caller class code actually is contained within an addAnimal method. Maybe NetBeans didn't update and remove the error after I encapsulated the  code in a method because the class hadn't been saved?