# How do classes differ from methods? Java not recognizing external classes

Tags: java, class, methods

Apologies for an elementary question, as this is my first ever programming class.

I've been going over 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151218/method-calls-inside-a-java-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300361/java-class-not-recognizing-external-method) and I'm positive this is referencing my problem but could someone break down how these are effecting me?

Via trial and error I know that the shuffle command is working fine as it works  within the class.  It stops working when I drop it into it's separate method though.

```
    package pokemon.pkgcatch;


    public class PokemonCatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    final String PlayerName; 
    int[][] MyPkmn;

    //Create a scanner to read input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    Scanner wildInput = new Scanner(new File("WildPkmn.txt"));
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(new File("MyPkmn.txt"));

//Create a random object to roll die
    Random rand = new Random(); 


    System.out.print("Welcome to the world of Pokemon, Trainer! "
                     + " What is your name? ");
    //Intro. Save playerName variable and create a doc for player's Pkmn
    PlayerName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Here's your first Pokemon. It's a little weak"
                       + " but you'll just have to catch stronger ones.");

            /**
            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("MyPkmn.txt")) {
                writer.println("int[][] MyPkmn =");
                writer.println("{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}");
                writer.println("};");
            }
            */

    ArrayList<String> PokeBelt = new ArrayList<String>();   
            PokeBelt.add("{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}");

    ArrayList<String> WildPkmn = new ArrayList<String>();
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");   
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 18, 16, 12, 10, 8}");
            WildPkmn.add("{0, 18, 16, 12, 10, 8}");

    System.out.println("The tall grass has " +
                   WildPkmn.size() +
                   " arrays stored in it.");

    //    for (int index = 0; index < WildPkmn.size(); index++)
    //         System.out.println(WildPkmn.get(index));

    System.out.println("The Ultimate Pokemon is out there somewhere. " +
                 "It's your job to catch it!");

Collections.shuffle(WildPkmn);
System.out.println(WildPkmn);

encounter();
        }       }   

public static encounter()
{
Collections.shuffle(WildPkmn);
System.out.println(WildPkmn);
System.out.println("You take a walk in the tall grass.");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to ask for apologies for a question. Here is the right place to ask questions about Java in this case.

One thing is clear from the code you've posted. You lack of Java fundamental knowledge so you should study the language in order to understand them.

**What went wrong**

If you compile the code the compiler will show show you the (syntactical) errors, which were the following.

- Imports missing

You are using the `ArrayList` class in your code **but you have not defined** **this class** anywhere. The compiler tried to search its definition in the file but failed, so it does not know what an object of `ArrayList` does.

One example in your code is where you calling the `add()` method on the`WildPkmn`object which is of type `ArrayList`.

`WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");`

The `ArrayList` class is a well known Java class and it's [defined in the java.util package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). So you **need to import this class** so the compiler can refer to this definiotion. This is done by the `import java.util.ArrayList` statement.

- Method definition

In Java every method needs to return an object or a value or... nothing. When the latter is the case you return `void`. That's what you've missed at the `encounter()` method's definition. You forgot to return `void`.

Finally, you are using the variable `WildPkmn`inside the `encounter()`. This variable is defined inside `main()` and **it's only visible in the method's scope that it was defined** (inside `main()`'s brackets). It's not visible inside the `encounter()`.

You should pass this variable from `main()` to `encounter()` as a parameter. See the (syntactically) correct version of this code bellow, to check how it's done.

```
package pokemon.pkgcatch;

// All the classes that you've used are imported here.
// Now the compiler knows where to look for their definitions.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.File;

 public class PokemonCatch {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     final String PlayerName;
     int[][] MyPkmn;

     //Create a scanner to read input
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner wildInput = new Scanner(new File("WildPkmn.txt"));
     Scanner myInput = new Scanner(new File("MyPkmn.txt"));

     //Create a random object to roll die
     Random rand = new Random();

     System.out.print("Welcome to the world of Pokemon, Trainer! "
                      + " What is your name? ");
     //Intro. Save playerName variable and create a doc for player's Pkmn
     PlayerName = keyboard.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Here's your first Pokemon. It's a little weak"
                        + " but you'll just have to catch stronger ones.");

     ArrayList<String> PokeBelt = new ArrayList<String>();
             PokeBelt.add("{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}");

     ArrayList<String> WildPkmn = new ArrayList<String>();
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 18, 16, 12, 10, 8}");
             WildPkmn.add("{0, 18, 16, 12, 10, 8}");

     System.out.println("The tall grass has " +
                    WildPkmn.size() +
                    " arrays stored in it.");

     System.out.println("The Ultimate Pokemon is out there somewhere. " +
                  "It's your job to catch it!");

     Collections.shuffle(WildPkmn);
     System.out.println(WildPkmn);

     encounter(WildPkmn); // pass the variable WildPkmn to the encounter
  }

  public static void encounter(ArrayList<String> list /* Now the encounter() method expects a variable of type ArrayList*/){
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println("You take a walk in the tall grass.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is unrelated to those two questions. You are trying to access a local variable of another method. By definition, this won't work, because local variables are only visible within the method they are declared in.

Instead, you have two options:

1. Declare the variable as a static variable in your class
2. Or, pass the variable as a method parameter.

Also, you are missing the word `void` between `public static` and `encounter()` - all methods in Java need to have a return type, even if they return nothing - and your final `}` needs to be moved to the end of the file - all methods in Java need to be inside a class.